# PHP array и дерево

Tags: php

у меня есть база с подобным набором данных

`+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | parent_id | is_active |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         0 | true      |
|  2 |         1 | false     |
|  3 |         2 | true      |
+----+-----------+-----------+`

функция, которая выстраивает дерево

```
function build(array $users = []): array
{
    $res = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $res[$user['id']]['user'] = $user;
        $childUsers = \getChild($user['id']);
        if (empty($childUsers)) {
            $res[$user['id']]['child'] = null;
            continue;
        }
        $res[$user['id']]['child'] = \build($childUsers);
        continue;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

getChild - получение детей из БД.

Моя основная проблема - не могу догадаться, как применить условие активности пользователя, т.е. в моем примере, все дети пользователя #2 должны стать детьми пользователя #1.

Comment: т.е. если один из узлов не активный, то он, типа как, схлопывается? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @rjhdby все правильно. если не активен, чилды должны попадать паренту

Comment: Строите дерево без оглядки на активность. Потом удаляете неактивные узлы с пробросом новых ребер

Comment: @rjhdby понял. думал без этого обойтись смогу

Comment: Можно обойтись. Например создав массив подстановок. При обнаружении, что узел недоступен, добавляем в него запись `[node=>parent]` и на каждой итерации производить рекурсивную 
 сверку с заменой. Но мне кажется, что такой вариант вам совсем не понравится :) Единственная надежда, что вопрос увидит знаток теории графов и выдаст убер-алгоритм для подобных случаев

Comment: пожалуй не буду усложнять =)